# Point to external files with Jinja in Sphinx

Tags: python, jinja2, documentation, python-sphinx

I'm extending a layout in Sphinx with Jinja.
With pathto(), I'm able to access files within my `build` folder. I can also access external websites with a conventional URL (e.g. https[:]//anywebsite[.]com). However, I'm not able to access files that are located outside my active build folder. I want to point to a second ToC in a subfolder within my project.

My project consists of a single `source` directory and three different `build` directories. My tree structure looks like this:

```
C:.
|   make.bat
|   Makefile   
+---adminbuild    # Build directory for admins        
+---build         # Build directory for users
+---devbuild      # Build directory for developers
+---env           
\---source
    |   conf.py
    |   contents.rst
    +---pics
    +---_static
    \---_templates
            index.html
            layout.html
```

As you can see, I have a custom landing page in the _templates folder (i.e., index.html), and a Jinja template (layout.html) extending my default layout.

I can access my ToC without any issues when I do this:

```
<a href="{{ pathto('contents') }}" class="btn btn-primary show-white"> Bla Bla Bla &rarr;</a>>
```

However, I cannot access the external ToC that is located in the second subfolder if I use the following:

```
<a href="{{ pathto('../adminbuild/contents.html') }}" class="btn btn-primary show-white">Bla Bla Bla</a>
```

How do you access files outside the default build folder with Jinja? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem on my own. :-)

For anybody running into a similar issue, here's what I did:

I created a second project and moved the second subfolder to the new project.

Since I'm testing locally, I'm running my localhosts as follows:

1. First project: `http://localhost:port-number-1`
2. Second project: `http://localhost:port-number-2`

Then, in my Jinja template inside the first project, I simply put this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:port-number-2/contents.html" class="btn btn-primary show-white">Bla Bla Bla &rarr;</a>
```

That's it! Everything is running as expected now.

Don't forget to adapt your Jinja template in the second project to reflect the changes accordingly.

Note that you're not forced to create a second project to implement this solution. Nevertheless, for my particular scenario, I'm creating separate projects within a structure that better suits my requirements.